# what property can be used in xml to auto import csv file in to a form?

Tags: javascript, java, groovy

I have exported a file and saved it as .csv, now I need an auto import functionality as soon I generate/export a file and save it as csv.

ex: i have saved it on my desktop/ in any drive location.

source i am generating file is from medis suite 4.0 application which will be used for CMR readings.
.

any suggestions appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. What application should auto import the csv file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.